# Why Twitter Login Verification (2FA) now by SMS only (previously had push notification)?

Tags: twitter, security

Why did Twitter Change Login Verification (2 Factor Authentication) to be via sms only vs push notifications as of March 21, 2016?

---

[Twitter Login Verification Article](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170388):

> **If you enrolled in login verification before March 21, 2016:**
>
> When you log in to your account on twitter.com or on another device using Twitter for iOS, Twitter for Android, or mobile.twitter.com, a push notification will be sent to your phone. Open the push notification to approve the login request. Once you approve, you will be immediately logged in to your account on twitter.com.

---

Forced me to use SMS on account I just set up (used same phone number as other account but that shouldn't matter).